# Run a function in tryCatch in case of error/warning

Tags: r, try-catch

I'm using a `tryCatch` function in which I want another function to be run in case of error/warning. This other function depends on some arguments and for some reason, `tryCatch` does not recognize them when they are the error and warning functions. 
Here is a simplified function where I'm facing the same problem:

```
essai <- function(x){
 y <- 2
 result <- tryCatch({
  sqrt(x*y)
 } , warning = function(cond,x,y) {
  message(cond)
  sqrt(abs(x*y))
 } , error = function(cond,x,y) {
  message(cond)
  sqrt(abs(x*y))
 } , finally = {
  message("done")
 } )
}

nbs <- c(1,2,3,-1,-2)
lapply(nbs, essai)
```

But here I have an error message saying `Error in value[[3L]](cond) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`. R doesn't understand it has to reuse x and y used in the failed function, why?

Comment: Why would it know to pass in x to x and y to y in your warning/error function?  There is no reason it should.  But if you remove the x and y parameters to your warning/error functions you can just use x and y directly since they'll be grabbed from the calling environment.  On a side note I have to assume this isn't your actual use case since you could just use `sqrt(abs(x*y))` directly in that case.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it an artificial and simplified function reproducing my problem
Though this is not very clear in which cases I shall put the arguments or not

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'is not very clear in which case I shall put the arguments or not' since the error/warning functions can't take any additional arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error` and `warning` take functions of one argument. This works fine:

```
essai <- function(x, cond = 'problem'){
  y <- 2
  result <- tryCatch({
    sqrt(x*y)
  } , warning = function(w) {
    message(cond)
    sqrt(abs(x*y))
  } , error = function(e) {
    message(cond)
    sqrt(abs(x*y))
  } , finally = {
    message("done")
  } )
}
```

The rest of the arguments can be specified in your `essai` function and will be available from both warning and error.

```
nbs <- c(1,2,3,-1,-2)
lapply(nbs, essai)
#done
#done
#done
#problem
#done
#problem
#done
# [[1]]
# [1] 1.414214
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2.44949
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1.414214
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Would there be a nice way to merge error and warning block into one if the functionality is identical?